# Does code style really matter in terms of application performance?

Tags: dart

e.g.
DO name types using UpperCamelCase.

```
class SliderMenu 
class HttpRequest
typedef Predicate<T> = bool Function(T value);
```

DO place “dart:” imports before other imports.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html'

import 'package:bar/bar.dart';
import 'package:foo/foo.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

if you look at [Effective Dart: Style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style), then no rule there affects performance. The same goes for [Documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation) (obviously).

For [Usage](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage) and [Design](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design), the answer is not as clear-cut. Some recommendations do affect performance, others do not (naming, for example, does not).

All of the recommendations are there to improve *readability*, so it affects user efficiency, even if it doesn't affect the program's run-time performance.

Comment: I was hoping for micro-improvements from this. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You can probably get micro (nay, nano!) improvements in the compile time from using one-letter names and removing all whitespace and comments. The parser will have to look at fewer bytes after all. It is *definitely* not worth it :)